# Is Doug pronounced dug or door-g?

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech

I remember many years ago when I was in Durham, UK, people pronounce the name Doug as door-g. However, I look up the dictionary and Oxford dict online and many other sources, they clearly say that British pronunciation of Doug is dug. Is Doug pronounced dug world wide? Could somebody explain? Any corrections are welcomed.

Comment: Most Northern accents in Britain pronounce the vowel in ***hut, but, Doug[las]*** like the vowel in ***foot, root,...*** If you spent time in Durham you should have noticed that.

Comment: See [this metafilter post](https://ask.metafilter.com/149866/Irish-Dougie). I never thought of the possibility that ***Doug / Dougie*** might be diminutives of the (primarily *Scottish*) name ***Dougal*** (rhymes with ***Google***). In that case, even Southerners would presumably enunciate the diminutives using ***oo*** rather than ***u.***

Comment: How would you pronounce "door-g"? I assume that's a non-rhotic accent? Not rolling your R but is the vowel r-coloured? There's still quite a few pronunciations possible. Other words with the same vowel?

Comment: It also depends on whether their name is Douglas or Dougal.

Comment: Please use IPA. Please don't add an R to a word in your spelling pronunciations to mean something that isn't the R sound: it is opaque to most native speakers of English.